# Incrementing JSON field using PUT and update() mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to simply add 1 to a variable I have stored in a JSON file.

This is what I'm using to accomplish this:

```
app.put('/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber/incrementFlagCount', function (req, res) {
        console.log("incrementing flag count now");

        mongoose.model('Listing').findOne(req.street, req.buildingNumber, req.apartmentNumber, function(err, listing){
            listing.update({
             //   $inc : {flagCount : 1}
                flagCount : flagCount+1
            },function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.send("There was a problem incrementing the flagCount of a listing: " + err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Flag count after=" + listing.flagCount);
                    res.json(listing.flagCount);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I'm getting the following error: `ReferenceError: flagCount is not defined`
This is how the JSON looks in mongolab:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "566c4bbabcda51a9eef08578"
    },
    "street": "test",
    "buildingNumber": 1,
    "apartmentNumber": 1,
    "beds": 1,
    "price": 1,
    "flagCount": 3,
    "owner": "56472a83bd9fa764158d0cb6"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to increment the `flagCount` by 1.

Comment: Try listing.update.flagCount

Comment: @Manu got TypeError: listing.update.flagCount is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `findOne` and `update` with flagCount are incorrect. `findOne` needs an object of conditions.

You also should use `req.params.street` instead of `req.street`, etc.

Rather than a find and then update, how about using findOneAndUpdate?

```
mongoose.model('Listing').findOneAndUpdate({street: req.params.street, 
buildingNumber: req.params.buildingNumber,
apartmentNumber: req.params.apartmentNumber}, {$inc: {flagCount: 1}}, 
    function(err, listing) {
     /// do stuff 
})
```